# Laravel Date comparison not working in Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I do not understand why but following query return null resultset.

`due_date` is Carbon date and `$now=Carbon:today();`

```
$subQuery = BillTable::where('busi_id', $business->busi_id)
        ->where('due_date','>=',$now)
        ->where('due_date','<',$now->addMonth())
        ->get();
```

Also when I use `whereBetween` it doesn't work.

```
$subQuery = BillTable::where('busi_id', $business->busi_id)
        ->whereBetween('due_date',[$now, $now->addMonth()])
        ->get();
```

But when I just to greater than or lesser than it works

```
$subQuery = BillTable::where('busi_id', $business->busi_id)
        ->where('due_date','>',$now->addWeek())
        ->get();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That would be silly of me, If I didn't check that already. Thanks for pointing it but that isn't the reason.

Comment: log $now because sometimes mysql and php's time are not in sync mysql might have local time and php will use UTC.

Comment: I just found that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the same instance for both range limits. When you call `addMonth` you add the month to the instance stored in `$now`. The two examples below illustrate the issue:

**1.** Using and modifying the same variable in two separate statements works as you'd expect:

```php
$now = Carbon::now();

dump($now); // prints 2015-12-12 14:50:00.000000
dump($now->addMonth); // prints 2016-01-12 14:50:00.000000
```

**2.** Using the same variable and modifying it in the same statement that passes the values to a method, will work differently, because it will be evaluated before being passed to the method. Meaning that both parameters will be equal because they both contain the same instance from the `$now` variable, which after getting evaluated will contain the `DateTime` of one month from now.

```php
$now = Carbon::now();

// Calling `addMonth` will change the value stored in `$now`
dump($now, $now->addMonth());

// The above statement prints two identical DateTime values a month from now:
// 2016-01-12 14:50:00.000000 and 2016-01-12 14:50:00.000000
```

This means that your current code was checking if the entries were due only **exactly** one month from now.

---

To fix it you need to use two instances in two separate variables:

```php
$from = Carbon::now();
$to = Carbon::now()->addMonth();

$subQuery = BillTable::where('busi_id', $business->busi_id)
                     ->whereBetween('due_date',[$from, $to])
                     ->get();
```

Comment: Now that this is working is it possible to have different date ranges and group them with a name 'today', 'nextweek', 'priviousweek' etc in a single query. I did this in SQL but not able to write in eloquent, and I want to use eloquent to be able to use Carbon (helps with timezone).

Comment: I don't know how to explain this `$subQuery = BillTable::where('busi_id', $business->busi_id)
  ->->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
        ->whereBetween('due_date',[$now, $now->addMonth()]) As rangename
  ->whereBetween('due_date',[$now, $now->addMonth()]) As rangename
  ->groupBy('rangename')
        ->get();`

Comment: I used the following sql case `DB::raw("CASE
       WHEN (to_days(invd_invoiceduedate) = to_days(now()))
         THEN 'due_today'
       WHEN (to_days(invd_invoiceduedate) BETWEEN (to_days(now()) - 7) AND to_days(now()))
         THEN 'overdue_7_days'
       WHEN (to_days(invd_invoiceduedate) BETWEEN (to_days(now()) - 15) AND (to_days(now()) - 8))
         THEN 'overdue_8_to_15_days'
       END invoice_age, sum(invd_invoicetotal) as invoice_sub_total"))` than group by invoice_age.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is because I used '$now' in the query.

Like is said before the query I did `$now=Carbon::today();` and use `$now` in the query.

But then I got rid of that and changed the query to use Carbon::today() it worked.

```
$subQuery = BillTable::where('busi_id', $business->busi_id)
    ->whereBetween('due_date',[Carbon::today(), Carbon::today()->addMonth())
    ->get();
```

It is weird.

Thanks,

K

Comment: I've just posted an answer on why that is a minute ago :).